# Return Object Outside of Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to return an object outside of a function. I'm using an Angular JS promise to log the `availableProviders` when they've been loaded, which is logging correctly to my console.

```
function getServiceProviders(serviceId) {
  var serviceProviders = ref.child('services').child(serviceId).child('providers');
  var providers = ref.child('providers');

  serviceProviders.on('value', function(snapshot) {        // on services.serviceId.providers
    var availableProviders = {};                           // create empty availableProviders array

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {             // for each provider in services.serviceId.providers
      var key = childSnapshot.key();                       // grab each provider's key
      providers.on('value', function(snap) {               // on providers
        if (snap.hasChild(key)) {                          // if providers has a child that matches the var key above
          var item = snap.child(key);                      // store that child in a var called item
          availableProviders[item.key()] = item.val();     // add item to availableProviders array
        }
      });
    });                                                    // rinse and repeat

    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.promise
      .then(function() {
        console.log(availableProviders);
      })

    defer.resolve();
  });

  return availableProviders;
}
```

I want the `getServiceProviders()` function to return these `availableProviders, but I'm getting this error as`availableProviders` isn't defined outside of that function.

```
ReferenceError: availableProviders is not defined
```

Is there any way around this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem related to Closures in JavaScript, I think you need to move `var availableProviders = {};` outside `serviceProviders.on('value', function(snapshot) {` function will fix your issue.

**Code**

```
function getServiceProviders(serviceId) {
    var serviceProviders = ref.child('services').child(serviceId).child('providers');
    var providers = ref.child('providers');
    var availableProviders = {}; // <==made it global
    serviceProviders.on('value', function(snapshot) { // on services.serviceId.providers

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) { // for each provider in services.serviceId.providers
            var key = childSnapshot.key(); // grab each provider's key
            providers.on('value', function(snap) { // on providers
                if (snap.hasChild(key)) { // if providers has a child that matches the var key above
                    var item = snap.child(key); // store that child in a var called item
                    availableProviders[item.key()] = item.val(); // add item to availableProviders array
                }
            });
        }); // rinse and repeat

        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.promise
            .then(function() {
                console.log(availableProviders);
            })

        defer.resolve();
    });

    return availableProviders;
}
```

Comment: Aha! So it was as easy as making the defining the `availableProviders` globally?

Comment: Ya..it was easy..Deferred shouldn't be there.because it is doing nothing

Comment: @realph Glad to hear it helped you.Don't forget accept answer..Thanks.